How to transform a centos .ova virtual machine into a docker image
I want to turn my centos 7 virtual machine which is working perfectly with services into a docker image and upload it to docker hub.
I tried to copy some ansible and services specific files.
I want to turn my centos 7 virtual machine which is working perfectly with services into a docker image and upload it to docker hub.
I tried to copy some ansible and services specific files.

How to convert VM image to dockerfile? has some suggestions.  In general, though, the operating models for Docker and VMs are quite different: a Docker container wraps a single process, and you'd typically run each of your services in a separate container.

It is not possible to "transform" a virtual machine into a docker image in a way that makes "sense". Moreover, a virtual machine has discs, which contain partition structure, boot information, which is just not representable in docker.
All in all, you can unpack the .ova virtual machine by loop mounting it, detecting partitions and mounting the file system, then create a .tar.gz with all the files inside and docker load the files. This will create a docker image with the same files as inside the virtual machine. This will also defeat one of the reasons docker exists - reproducibility.
